# Google Ecommerce Tracking Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am confused about google's ecommerce tracking which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce . It tells me to insert the tracking code into my finished "thank you" page.

But my question is, if I have different items where a customer doesn't buy multiple items but only 1 item, while another customer buys another item, how does it know the total cost or which item was bought?

So going by google's example, my code would look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Receipt for your clothing purchase from Acme Clothing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);

   // add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
   // where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
   // prints out _addItem for each
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
    'T-Shirt',        // product name
    'Green Medium',   // category or variation
    '11.99',          // unit price - required
    '1'               // quantity - required
  ]);

   _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '2468',           // transaction ID - required
    'VBE12',           // SKU/code - required
    'Pants',        // product name
    'Small Blue',   // category or variation
    '100.43',          // unit price - required
    '1'               // quantity - required
  ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
```

But how would it know that my total is not 11.99 but 100.43 instead if another customer bought the Pants instead of the T-Shirt if I am the one declaring 11.99 on the code itself?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Additional Info: I am using paypal where I have 3 options for users where they can purchase 1 month, 6 months or 1 year. Do I get transaction ID from them? Or do I create my own transaction ID?

EDIT1:

```
<form onsubmit="trackSubmit('1 Month', 'clickedOn1Month', 'Linkfor1Month')" 
                    onclick="
                        _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
                        '1',           // transaction ID - required
                        '1 Month',  // affiliation or store name
                        '11.99',          // total - required
                        '1.29',           // tax
                        '5',              // shipping
                        'San Jose',       // city
                        'California',     // state or province
                        'USA'             // country
                      ]);" 
                    action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXX">
                    <input type="image" src="pay1month.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how would it know that my total is not 11.99 but 100.43 instead if
>   another customer bought the Pants instead of the T-Shirt if I am the
>   one declaring 11.99 on the code itself?

Everything is tied to a transaction just as it should be in your back end application. This is not supposed to be your backend accounting system. It is supposed to help you see what people are buying and where they are from (and other analytics).

> Do I get transaction ID from them? Or do I create my own transaction
>   ID?

This should be an id that you can tie into your accounting.

**More info**
Just to be clear:

The JavaScript tracker uses a queue mechanism in the form of a JavaScript array (called _gaq). What happens is you can push functions and their parameters (packaged as an array) onto this global array (_gaq). At some point the tracker script pops the items off the queues and calls them, sending them to the tracking server.

Just as in the example you provided, **you** need to write javascript that sets everything up.

Assuming you have control of your own inventory the page flow would probably be more like this:

**When the page loads (put in head with async='true' or at the end of page right before closing body tag)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];    //  Creates or references the global queue
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);     //     Sets the google tracking account id
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);    //  Tracks the page

  //    The rest installs the javascript tracker to the page
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

**At some point the user submits the form you need to be in control of that submission and do the following before sending to paypal**

```
     _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);
```

You must generate the values above which are only meaningful to your company. The transaction id will be used for tracking the rest of the items and may have more or less meaning for your company.

Then you will need to add each item with the same transaction id as above and again you are supplying the data that is meaningful to you and your company.

```
   // add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
   // where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
   // prints out _addItem for each
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
    'T-Shirt',        // product name
    'Green Medium',   // category or variation
    '11.99',          // unit price - required
    '1'               // quantity - required
  ]);
```

and finally seal the deal, google-wise:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers
```

THEN you send the stuff to PayPal.

More info:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#keyComponents

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. I am trying to see what people are buying and where they are from, that was mainly my question. I am not trying to make it my backend accounting system. But how do I use that Google ecommerce Tracking code to see which paypal button they clicked on and then returned to after purchasing it when it looks like it's telling me to define which one they bought when I don't know until they buy it?

Comment: That will depend on how your site implements things.

Comment: I basically just use paypal's form system, copy and paste the purchase button and when they make a purchase, it redirects them to a simple "thank you" page on my site.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry but I'm still kind of confused. For "controlling" the submission, do you mean something like this? If I have my paypal button as shown in my edit1 post.